# PHP is date past due?

Tags: php

Ok, I have a "due date" formatted like this: 08/31/2012 (M/D/Y). What I would like to do using PHP compare the returned string as shown against the current date. If the string above is older than the current date...execute some code.

I know this seems simple but it is throwing me for a loop.

thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean that if the string-date is older do this and if not do that?

```
<?php

$string = '08/31/2012';
if(strtotime($string) < time()){
    echo 'Old';
}else{
    echo 'Not happened yet';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change to format `YYYY-MM-DD` and compare simply as string.